# Validar un email en JavaScript que acepte todos los caracteres latinos

Tags: javascript, validación, email, regex

#### Pregunta

¿Cómo validar un e-mail que acepte todos los caracteres latinos?

- Por caracteres latinos me refiero a letras acentuadas, `ñ`, `ç`, y todas las usadas por idiomas como español, portugués, italiano... latinos.

#### Contexto

- El objetivo es mostrar un icono al lado del texto a medida que el usuario va tipeando su dirección de mail.
- No me interesa aceptar todos los casos válidos. Fue una decisión de diseño abarcar sólo los mails más frecuentes. Es decir, letras (incluyendo acentos y similares) y los símbolos `._%+-`.
- Puedo usar código de otras fuentes, siempre y cuando sean populares (ej: jQuery).

#### Código

```js
document.getElementById('email').addEventListener('input', function() {
    campo = event.target;
    valido = document.getElementById('emailOK');
        
    emailRegex = /^[-\w.%+]{1,64}@(?:[A-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.){1,125}[A-Z]{2,63}$/i;
    //Se muestra un texto a modo de ejemplo, luego va a ser un icono
    if (emailRegex.test(campo.value)) {
      valido.innerText = "válido";
    } else {
      valido.innerText = "incorrecto";
    }
});
```

```html
<p>
    Email:
    <input id="email">
    <span id="emailOK"></span>
</p>
```

#### Casos

Estoy usando el regex

```
/^[-\w.%+]{1,64}@(?:[A-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.){1,125}[A-Z]{2,63}$/i
```

Que funciona perfecto en casos como

```
abcde.fghi@gmail.com
nombre-apellido@do-mi-nio.info
```

Pero falla con acentos y otras letras latinas

```
germán@bla.com
yo@mi-compañía.com
estação@brasil.com.br
```

Comment: En serio tenes direcciones e-mail con acentos? En tal caso, las clases (grupos entre corchetes) pueden incluir cosas como áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚäëïöüÄËÏÖÜàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙñÑ

Comment: como [-\w.%+áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚäëïöüÄËÏÖÜàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙñÑ]

Comment: En Javascript no (en otros lenguajes como PHP y Python sí, pero es más jodido)

Comment: ¿Exáctamente a qué hace referencia cuando menciona 'Carácter latino'?

Comment: Mariano: Te sugiero mencionar que ya es permitido el uso de caracteres internacionales. Por ejemplo, puedes agregar como referencia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_email.

Comment: No está de mas validar un dato desde cliente, pero si no lo validas desde servidor no sirve de nada.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Con esta expresión regular puedes validar cualquier dirección de correo elecrónico que contenga caracteres Unicode:

```
/^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i
```

Si lo pruebas en una consola de JavaScript:

```
> emailRegex.test("abcde.fghi@gmail.com");
< true
> emailRegex.test("germán@bla.com");
< true
```

[**Fuente**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181)

---

A partir de ahí, y como muy bien has mencionado, una expresión que se ajusta más a tus necesidades sería la siguiente:

```
/^(?:[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+)*|"[^\n"]+")@(?:[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@"]{2,63}$/i
```

Comment: Esa expresión regular la ví en una respuesta del stackoverflow inglés, y objetaban que acepta muchos emails no ICANN como `**@as`, ya que esa expresión regular no controla que el dominio deba tener al menos un punto (un dominio), que el nombre de usuario no sea mayor de 255 carácteres, etc. Este e-mail también parece que se lo tragaría: `juan@{{192.168.1.52}}`

Comment: @Peregring-lk Gracias por agregar los comentarios explicando la diferencia de RFC vs ICANN. Mi pregunta nunca apuntó a validar *todos* los posibles formatos de e-mail (eso es imposible), aclarando que "*fue una decisión de diseño abarcar sólo los mails más frecuentes*". En particular, es una primera validación que cubre un altísimo porcentaje de direcciones. Pero como se argumenta [en la respuesta de Braiam](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/297/127), sólo se puede verificar enviando un mail. No obstante, este regex [sí valida que haya un punto en el dominio](https://regex101.com/r/3X8Gyk/1).

Answer (score 37):

Existen ciertas restricciones para emails pero puedo comentar que regularmente deben basarse en estas reglas:

> - Mayúsculas y minúsculas del alfabeto ingles.
> - Números de 0 al 9
> - puede contener punto pero no al inicio o repetirse.
> - puede usar los caracteres:  !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~

Existen restricciones con ciertos tipos de email por ejemplo si contienen:

> - Alfabeto griego.
> - Caracteres cirílicos.
> - Caracteres japoneses.
> - Alfabeto latín con diacríticos.

ejemplos no aceptados como direcciones validas de email:

```
червь.ca®rton@picnic.com

josé.patroñinio@hotdog.com
```

Ver más :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322

Imagino un email con caracteres cirilicos, peor aún si lo que quieres es almacenar esos datos en una BD, que tipo de SQL collation utilizar!

Pero bueno la pregunta se refiere a como validar ese tipo de emails, este es un script que ayudaría con la tarea:

```
function validarEmail(valor) {
  if (/^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i.test(valor)){
   alert("La dirección de email " + valor + " es correcta!.");
  } else {
   alert("La dirección de email es incorrecta!.");
  }
}
```

por ejemplo:

```
validarEmail("jorgésys.boc+al@hotflow.com");
```

El script te mostraría que la dirección email es correcta.

---

- Actualización:

Actualmente ya [es posible usar caracteres internacionales en nombres de dominio y direcciones de correo electrónico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_email).

Las direcciones de correo electrónico tradicionales están limitadas a los caracteres del alfabeto inglés y algunos otros caracteres especiales. Las siguientes son direcciones de correo electrónico tradicionales válidas:

```
  Abc@example.com                                (English, ASCII)
  Abc.123@example.com                            (English, ASCII)
  user+mailbox/department=shipping@example.com   (English, ASCII)
  !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`.{|}~@example.com               (English, ASCII)
  "Abc@def"@example.com                          (English, ASCII)
  "Fred Bloggs"@example.com                      (English, ASCII)
  "Joe.\\Blow"@example.com                       (English, ASCII)
```

El correo electrónico internacional, por el contrario, utiliza caracteres [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) codificados como [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), lo que permite codificar el texto de las direcciones en la mayoría de los sistemas de escritura del mundo.

Las siguientes son todas las direcciones de correo electrónico internacionales válidas:

```
  用户@例子.广告                   (Chinese, Unicode)
  अजय@डाटा.भारत                    (Hindi, Unicode)
  квіточка@пошта.укр             (Ukrainian, Unicode)
  θσερ@εχαμπλε.ψομ               (Greek, Unicode)
  Dörte@Sörensen.example.com     (German, Unicode)
  аджай@экзампл.рус              (Russian, Unicode)
```

Comment: Gracias por el dato. Realmente me sirve. Si bien el alcance definido no debe cubrir todo el RFC, sino más bien los casos más genéricos, me interesa evaluarlo como opción: ¿Cómo se implementaría esto en JavaScript?

Comment: Es un punto totalmente válido... Creo que si pensás que no debería validarse, debería estar explícito en la respuesta. Este tipo de respuestas bien fundamentadas me sirve para definir el alcance.

Answer (score 20):

He encontrado un artículo [aquí](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) (en Inglés) que habla de algunas declaraciones diferentes expresiones regulares que pueden verificar direcciones de correo electrónico basados en el estándar RFC. Hay muchas declaraciones de expresiones regulares recomendada diferentes y no hay un único todo-en-una solución. Pero esta expresión regular es probablemente el que me iría con, añadiendo caracteres acentuados a la lista de caracteres válidos también.

```
\A[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\z
```

Comment: Y ¿Cómo sería una versión que funcione en JavaScript y que acepte acentos y demás caracteres latinos?

Comment: El problema es que un email RFC-válido podría ser ICANN-inválido. Es decir, que RFC lo permita pero no haya ningún proveedor que te permita tener emails con esas direcciones.

Answer (score 17):

> ¿Cómo validar un email que acepte todos los caracteres latinos?

La única forma 100% segura de verificar si un email es valido es enviando uno. Si el usuario escribio el correo mal, ellos simplemente reintentaran.

Según [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4), `presidencia@gobierno.pais` es un email "valido", pero,
¿alguien lo va a recibir? ¿Existe un servidor detras del dominio que acepte correos? Esas son las preocupaciones que deberias tener. Lo que seas que estas haciendo, una lista de distribución, registro, etc. debe de **enviar un correo de confirmación para validarlo**. La implementacion dependera del stack que uses (C#, PHP, Java?) y hací tendrás correos validos que alguien recibe.

Puedes implementar algo en el lado del cliente que al menos diga "este es una direción de correo electronico", pero no debería de ser tu herramienta de "validación", solo trata de que el usuario se de cuenta de que lo que escribió es #($^*%#$@^(*#$^.com. Si el cliente utiliza un navegador moderno, puedes utilizar [`<input type="email">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email) en tu formulario, esto eliminará la necesidad de mantener el regex.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, la única forma de validar es desde el server. Y sí, la idea es que sea una primera etapa de validación genérica, pero sin depender sólo en esto (al fin y al cabo JavaScript podría estar deshabilitado). Muy correcta tu visión, y es la forma en que lo quiero implementar.

Answer (score 16):

Simplemente señalar que, de acuerdo a la [especificación oficial](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#valid-e-mail-address), el REGEX que representa una dirección de email **ortográficamente** válida es el siguiente:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/
```

Puse a propósito el término *dirección de email **ortográficamente** válida*, porque lo que define una dirección de email **realmente** válida es que ésta funcione, es decir, que exista y pueda recibir emails.

De ahí se desprende que una verificación por medio de Javascript no es suficiente. Puede ayudarnos a hacer una **validación ortográfica**, a condición de que Javascript esté activado del lado del cliente.

Si se quiere verificar que el email **realmente existe**, no hay otra manera que enviando un email y que el destinatario responda. Es a eso a lo que se le puede llamar con toda propiedad **validación real de un email**.

De hecho, eso es lo que hacen todos los servicios de suscripción serios, nos envían un email que debemos verificar para quedar inscritos definitivamente en sus sitios o en sus listas de distribución.

Me permito mostrar gráficamente los pasos para **validar** un e-mail. Veremos que lo tratado aquí es apenas la etapa 2 de un proceso de validación que comprendería **5 etapas**:

- ***Etapa 1***: El usuario **escribe** un e-mail
- ***Etapa 2***: Validación **ortográfica** del e-mail escrito por el usuario
- ***Etapa 3***: Verificar si el dominio correspondiente al e-mail validado ortográficamente **posee un servidor de e-mail**
- ***Etapa 4***: Enviar una petición (ping) o un email para verificar que **el servidor está aceptando e-mails**
- ***Etapa 5***: El e-mail fue recibido correctamente en **esa dirección** y el usuario confirma de algún modo haberlo recibido (haciendo click en un enlace, enviando un email de respuesta, etc)

Hasta que no llegamos a la etapa 5, no podemos decir que el e-mail ha sido *validado*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si todos modos el OP solicita un método de validación que acepte direcciones con ñ y otros caracteres no definidos hasta el momento por la especificación oficial de w3.org (enlace de más arriba), el REGEX mencionado en una anterior respuesta funciona.

El código que sigue es el mismo usado en la pregunta, pero implementando por un lado el REGEX oficial y el REGEX que **permite** caracteres latinos tales como la ñ.

```js
document.getElementById('email').addEventListener('input', function() {
    campo = event.target;
    valido = document.getElementById('emailOK');
        
  var reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

 var regOficial = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;

    //Se muestra un texto a modo de ejemplo, luego va a ser un icono
    if (reg.test(campo.value) && regOficial.test(campo.value)) {
      valido.innerText = "válido oficial y extraoficialmente";
    } else if (reg.test(campo.value)) {
      valido.innerText = "válido extraoficialmente";

    } else {
      valido.innerText = "incorrecto";

}
});
```

```html
<p>
    Email:
    <input id="email">
    <span id="emailOK"></span>
</p>
```

### Validación ortográfica en HTML5

HTML5 permite declarar nuestro `input` del tipo email y se encarga (en parte) de la validación por nosotros, [como dice MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/HTML/HTML5/Formularios_en_HTML5):

> `email`: El atributo representa una dirección de correo electrónico. Los
> saltos de línea se eliminan automáticamente del valor ingresado. Puede
> ingresarse una dirección de correo no válida, pero el campo de ingreso
> sólo funcionará si la dirección  satisface la producción `ABNF 1*( atext / "." ) "@" ldh-str 1*( "." ldh-str )` donde `atext` está definida
> en [RFC 5322, sección 3.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.3) y `ldh-str` está definida en [RFC 1034, sección 3.5.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-3.5)

Se puede combinar `email` con el atributo [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input):

> `pattern` : Una expresión regular contra la que el valor es evaluado. El patrón
> debe coincidir con el valor completo, no solo una parte. Se puede usar
> el atributo title para describir el patrón como ayuda al usuario. Este
> atributo aplica cuando el atributo `type` es `text`, `search`, `tel`, `url`,
> `email`, o `password`, y en caso contrario es ignorado. El lenguaje de
> expresión regular es el mismo que el algoritmo RegExp de JavaScript,
> con el parámetro `'u'` que permite tratar al patrón como una secuencia
> de código Unicode. El patrón no va rodeado por diagonales.

La desventaja es que no todos los clientes son compatibles con HTML5.

```html
<form>
<input type="email" pattern='^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$' title="Entre un email válido"  placeholder="Entre su email">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Aparentemente omitiste la **Etapa 6** que es cuando el usuario hace *click* en un enlace específico y el servidor recibe la confirmación. Además este paso favorece la posibilidad de que el usuario vea realmente el mensaje (lo busque de ser necesario) y mejora la calificación NO-ES-SPAM de futuros mails que se envíen desde el mismo servidor/dominio.

Answer (score 13):

Según la RFC 6531 se tendrían que soportar más caracteres de a los que estamos acostumbrados. Pero los servidores lo limitan con otras anteriores.
No veo una solución con un rango único que implique introducir «todos los caracteres latinos». A pesar de que parece que van juntos (como en esta [tabla del 0080 al 00FF](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=128&number=128&utf8=string-literal&unicodeinhtml=hex)), hay otros por en medio.

Una posible regex para los caracteres latinos que podrían interesarte ([fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26841342/604694)) y añadiendo la ([sugerencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/142/validar-un-email-en-javascript/189?noredirect=1#comment206_189)):

```
/[A-Za-z\u0021-\u007F\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff]+/g
```

Se podría juntar con tu regex, las que ya han indicado anteriormente o una según la RFC 2822, como esta, para que no excluya los rangos que te interesan (que hay muchos tipos de tildes) ([fuente](https://regex101.com/r/sI6yF5/1)):

```
^([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x22([^\x0d\x22\x5c\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x22)(\x2e([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x22([^\x0d\x22\x5c\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x22))*\x40([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x5b([^\x0d\x5b-\x5d\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x5d)(\x2e([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x5b([^\x0d\x5b-\x5d\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x5d))*$
```

Comment: Buena respuesta. Sin duda sería ideal ajustarse a la RFC6531. Sin embargo, creo que no sería nada fácil implementarlo... En cuanto al primer regex, está dejando afuera varios caracteres del rango [\u0021-\u007F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block)) (por ejemplo los símbolos `_%+-`)... En cuanto al segundo, deja afuera a los caracteres acentuados (como `á = \u00E1 = \xc3\xa1`).

Comment: Estupendo. La primera regex que puse era para caracteres latinos, no los símbolos `_%+-` (la he editado para añadirlos). Respecto a la segunda ya advertí de que es según la RFC 2822, que se podía tomar de base para añadirle la primera o las de respuestas previas.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes probar con esta función;

```js
function validarEmail(email) {
  // Expresión regular para validar el formato del email
  var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/;

  // Validar el formato del email
  if (!regex.test(email)) {
    return false;
  }

  // Separar el nombre de usuario y el dominio del email
  var partes = email.split("@");
  var usuario = partes[0];
  var dominio = partes[1];

  // Validar que el usuario y el dominio no estén vacíos
  if (usuario.length === 0 || dominio.length === 0) {
    return false;
  }

  // Validar que el usuario y el dominio no contengan caracteres especiales
  var caracteresEspeciales = /[!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]/;
  if (caracteresEspeciales.test(usuario) || caracteresEspeciales.test(dominio)) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

// Ejemplo de uso
var email = "ejemplo@example.com";
if (validarEmail(email)) {
  console.log("Email válido");
} else {
  console.log("Email inválido");
}
```