# Validar email con una función en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap

Quiero validar los correos que tengo en un campo de texto pero no he encontrado el por que me presenta un error cuando se supone que el correo es valido, para esto utilizo un script.
Esto es lo que estoy haciendo

```js
// funcion para validar el correo
function caracteresCorreoValido(email, div){
    console.log(email);
    var email = $(email).val();
    var caract = new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/);

    if (caract.test(email) == false){
        $(div).hide().removeClass('hide').slideDown('fast');

        return false;
    }else{
        $(div).hide().addClass('hide').slideDown('slow');
//        $(div).html('');
        return true;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal m-t-20 toggle-disabled" onsubmit="validacionLogin(); return false;" method="post" >

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
<!--                                <label class="control-label">E-mail</label>-->
                                <input class="form-control input-lg" type="email" id="email" name="email" data-validation="email"  placeholder="Introduce tu correo electronico">
                                <div id="xmail" class="hide"><h6 class="text-danger">Ingresa un email valido</h6></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
<!--                                <label class="control-label">Contraseña</label>-->
                                <input class="form-control input-lg" type="password" id="password" name="password" data-validation="required" placeholder="Contraseña">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group text-center m-t-40">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg w-lg waves-effect waves-light" >Iniciar sesión</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form> 
                </div>

<script>
   // cuando pierde el foco, este valida si lo que esta en el campo de texto si es un correo o no y muestra una respuesta
   $('form').find('input[type=email]').blur(function(){
      caracteresCorreoValido($(this).val(), '#xmail')
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Con qué mail correcto te da error?

Comment: @Alan La expresión regular sería mucho más eficiente como [`/^[a-z0-9_.+-]+\@(?:[a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,63}$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/mA6lD7/1) Sin embargo, hay que tener en cuenta que tomará como válidas direcciones inválidas y viceversa. Relacionado: [Validar un email en JavaScript](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/142/validar-un-email-en-javascript)

Comment: Genial muchas gracias, muy buen aporte voy a revisarlo con mas detalle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Esta línea de código te sobra:

```
var email = $(email).val();
```

Ya estás pasando `email` como cadena de texto cuando llamas a la función, no hace falta que intentes leerlo de nuevo (lo que hará que email pierda su valor y te falle la lógica posterior).

Haciendo ese cambio, ya funciona bien:

```js
// funcion para validar el correo
function caracteresCorreoValido(email, div){
    console.log(email);
    //var email = $(email).val();
    var caract = new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/);

    if (caract.test(email) == false){
        $(div).hide().removeClass('hide').slideDown('fast');

        return false;
    }else{
        $(div).hide().addClass('hide').slideDown('slow');
//        $(div).html('');
        return true;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="panel-body">
  <form class="form-horizontal m-t-20 toggle-disabled" onsubmit="validacionLogin(); return false;" method="post" >

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <!--<label class="control-label">E-mail</label>-->
        <input class="form-control input-lg" type="email" id="email" name="email" data-validation="email"  placeholder="Introduce tu correo electronico">
        <div id="xmail" class="hide"><h6 class="text-danger">Ingresa un email valido</h6></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <!--<label class="control-label">Contraseña</label>-->
        <input class="form-control input-lg" type="password" id="password" name="password" data-validation="required" placeholder="Contraseña">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group text-center m-t-40">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg w-lg waves-effect waves-light" >Iniciar sesión</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form> 
</div>

<script>
  // cuando pierde el foco, este valida si lo que esta en el campo de texto si es un correo o no y muestra una respuesta
  $('form').find('input[type=email]').blur(function(){
    caracteresCorreoValido($(this).val(), '#xmail')
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la corrección , no se como se me pudo pasar eso por alto :(

Answer (score 7):

quizás la respuesta no tiene mucho que ver con `JavaScript` puro y crudo como se solicita, sin embargo por temas de validación de `inputs` siento que hay que compartirla :D

Antes de seguir quiero dejar en claro que la implementación por parte de los navegadores es lo suficientemente amplia como usarla con tranquilidad, revisar aquí: http://caniuse.com/#search=email

```css
body {
    padding-top: 15px;
}
div {
    width: 400px;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: right; 
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 3px;
}

.buttons {
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div>
        <label for="name">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" required />
    </div>

    <div>        
        <label for="comments">Correo:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" required />
    </div>
    
    <div class="buttons">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: 100% de acuerdo con esta respuesta. Si no tienes que soportar navegadores antiguos, deja que sea el navegador el que se encargue de cosas como ésta

Comment: gracias hermano :D sigamos motivando a la familia de SOes a que desarrolle con todo el power 2.0!

Answer (score 1):

Prueba no igualar el resultado del test y hacerlo como una llamada a una función

```
function caracteresCorreoValido(email, div){
    console.log(email);

    var caract = new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/);

    if (! caract.test(email)){
        $(div).hide().removeClass('hide').slideDown('fast');

        return false;
    }else{
        $(div).hide().addClass('hide').slideDown('slow');
//        $(div).html('');
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#correo').change(function (e) {
    var emailRegex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    var EmailId = this.value;
    if (emailRegex.test(EmailId))
        this.style.backgroundColor = "";
    else
        this.style.backgroundColor = "LightPink";
});
```

Comment: Hola Mauricio podrías explicar qué hace el código y por qué es la respuesta?