# ¿Por qué esta expresión regular en javascript falla?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/gmi
```

validando este texto

> dfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff

estoy haciendo esto

```
var value = 'dfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff';
var expression =  /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/gmi;

var status =  value.match(expression);
```

Comment: ¿Qué valida esa expresión? Y cómo la estás implementando?

Comment: Hola edwin, te aconsejo que te des el **[tour]** y también que revises **[ask]**

Comment: que el texto sea un email pero da un timeup el navegador se muere en chrome

Comment: Bueno es que la cadena de caracteres es demasiado larga, primeramente deberías validar tu frontend para que tu usuario no ponga una cadena tan larga.

Comment: @edwineka a que te refieres con que se muere el navegador

Comment: vale disculpa ya se cual es el error

Comment: editare mi respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Bueno el error que tienes por lo que veo es:

La expresión regular que tienes te tira el navegador, te recomiendo que se lo cambies por esto:

ANTES:

```
var value = 'dfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff';
var expression =  /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/gmi;

var status =  value.match(expression);
```

estas diciendo que haga una validación y verifique si contiene un `@` y un `.` pero debido a la que la variable `value` no contiene ningún `@` y ningún `.` te sale error te recomiendo que hagas esto:

DESPUÉS:

```
var value = 'dfffffffffffffffffffffff@ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff.fff';
var expression =  /^(?:[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+)*|"[^\n"]+")@(?:[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@"]{2,63}$/i;

var status =  value.match(expression);
```

<sup>* Expresión regular obtenida de [Validar un email en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/151/127).</sup>

o si quieres para que sea mas bonito puedes cambiar lo que contiene var por esto:

```
var value = 'Mi@prueba.com'; ( es un ejemplo por si lo quieres cambiar).
```

Espero y te funcione

> NOTA: LA CADENA DE CARACTERES ES DEMASIADO GRANDE PARA UN CORREO, TE RECOMIENDO QUE LO HAGAS MAS PEQUEÑO O QUE VALIDES QUE INGRESE UN MÍNIMO DE CARACTERES.

Answer (score -1):

En tu expresión estás poniendo que es obligatorio tener un @ en el medio y que debe finalizar con un punto y con 2 a 4 letras, por eso falla.
Si pones "dfffffffffffffffff@fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff.fff" funciona bien.