# Solamente permitir escribir un correo electrónico en EditText

Tags: java, android, regex, email, validación

He hecho este código para intentar que en `EditTextEmail` solamente se pueda escribir un *correo electrónico* si se escribe algo que no sea un *correo electrónico* mande un `Toast`

```
    EditText EditTextEmail;
    Button btn1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        EditTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextEmail);
        final String compruebaemail = EditTextEmail.getEditableText().toString().trim();


        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!compruebaemail.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+.[a-z]+"))
                {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Por favor, introduce bien su email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

El problema es básicamente que escriba lo que escriba mi manda el `Toast` como si estuviese mal escribo.

Ejemplo de texto con el que falla:

> ```
> ejemplo@hotmail.com
> ```

Comment: No le veo nada malo en logica (java), lo unico es que probando tu expresion regular me falla... prueba con esta respuesta, probe su expresion regular y funciona de maravilla
<br />
https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/151/27647
<br />
Lo probe en: http://www.regextester.com/

Comment: Sí! Eso era el error! Muchas gracias :D, escribe una respuesta con la solución y la marco como correcta! Y si puedes añadir la formula perfecta para: *Si bien deberías escapar el punto, permitir más de 1 punto, posiblemente permitir mayúsculas en el dominio, y permitir otros caracteres* te lo agradecería :) @Mariano

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La variable `compruebaemail` está siendo asignada en `onCreate`, antes de que ingreses el texto.

En cambio si se asigna dentro del evento `onClick`, recién ahí tendrá el último valor ingresado.

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final String compruebaemail = EditTextEmail.getEditableText().toString().trim();

        final String regex = "(?:[^<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+(?:\\.[^<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+)*|\"[^\\n\"]+\")@(?:[^<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+\\.)+[^<>()\\[\\]\\.,;:\\s@\"]{2,63}";

        if (!compruebaemail.matches(regex))
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Por favor, introduce bien su email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

---

Nótese que opté por otra expresión regular, tomada de la respuesta a mi pregunta: [Validar un email en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/142/127).

El problema que podía tener la expresión regular que estabas utilizando era que:

- había que escapar el punto (sino coincide con cualquier caracter)
- había que permitir más de 1 punto (ejemplo `usuario@hotmail.com.ar`)
- posiblemente permitir mayúsculas en el dominio (ya que sólo estabas permitiendo `[a-z]`, y las expresiones regulares diferencian mayúsculas/minúsculas por omisión)
- y permitir otros caracteres, válidos en cualquier e-mail (ejemplo: `+`).

El regex que utilicé, no válida absolutamente todos los mails válidos, pero en mi opinión te servirá para la mayoría de los casos. De hecho, si realmente se aceptarán todos los casos válidos según el RFC, estarías aceptando "*aberraciones*" que normalmente uno no quiere aceptar en un formulario. De todas formas, la validación de e-mail es un tema demasiado amplio que ya se escapa del alcance de esta pregunta.

Comment: Gracias! Solucionado :)

Comment: No obstante, por más que esté respondiendo directamente a tu pregunta, te recomiendo ver [la solución de @JorgeSys](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/74183/127), que creo que es más profesional, o menos "casera" de lo que estoy respondiendo

Answer (score 3):

Puedes realizar la validación  usando un `TextInputLayout` y utilizas 
 el método `setError()` para definir el mensaje, `setErrorEnabled()` para habilitarlo, por ejemplo:

```
//Validación de error en email, valida texto que ingresa el usuario en el EditText.
boolean emailError = validaEditTextEmail();

//Dependiendo del valor booleando al validar el email, muestra el mensaje:
TextInputLayout tilEmail = (TextInputLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.til_email);
tilEmail.setError(emailError ? "Ingrese un correo válido" : "");
tilEmail.setErrorEnabled(emailError);
```

Al detectar la validación un email incorrecto se habilita el mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrego un ejemplo de `TextInputLayout` para el ejemplo anterior:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mi_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/preg_correo"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

En este ejemplo, la validación se realiza sobre el texto introducido en el  `EdiText` con id `mi_email`, en base al valor obtenido determinamos mostrar o no el mensaje por medio del  `TextInputLayout`.

Comment: No es lo que busco, lo que tú comentas es para que el teclado solamente acepte letras/números/signos que acepte un email, lo que yo digo es para que `EditText` no acepte nada que no sea un email

Comment: @UserNameYo he editado mi respuesta, te recomiendo agregar un TextInputLayout

Answer (score 2):

Desde la version de **android 2.2+** existe este método:

```
public final static boolean esEmailValido(CharSequence email) {
   if (email== null) {
       return false;
   } else {
       return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
   }
}
```

Si quieres una alternativa, propongo lo siguiente:

```
public static boolean esEmailValido(String email) {
    String expresiones = "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expresiones, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

La implementación en tu código seria de la siguiente manera:

```
EditText EditTextEmail;
Button btn1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    EditTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextEmail);
    final String compruebaemail = EditTextEmail.getEditableText().toString().trim();


    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!esEmailValido(compruebaemail))
            {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Por favor, introduce bien su email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

    public static boolean esEmailValido(String email) {
        String expresiones = "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expresiones, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        return matcher.matches();
    }

}
```

Si quisieras usar el primer método, seria exactamente de la misma manera.

Comment: Cómo puedo implementar tu segunda idea a mi `EditText`, podrías añadirlo a tu respuesta?

Comment: Respuesta añadida, aun así recomendaria probar el primero de los dos metodos ya que es el "oficial" ofrecido por android.

Comment: Si bien `android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS` es la expresión implementada en Android, no se debe confiar ciegamente. Tiene algunos casos en los que falla y algunos casos "demasiado permisivos" que quizás uno no quiera aceptar. Recomiendo revisar la información que hay acerca de esta expresión antes de implementarla.

Comment: @Mariano si, en eso coincido contigo, si quieres "limitar" siempre sera mejor una regla personalizada.