# Como puedo validar un email en android

Tags: android, validación

Tengo este código para validar emails:

```
public static boolean validarEmail(String email) {
    Pattern pattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
    return pattern.matcher(email).matches();
}
```

Pero hay alguna otra forma mas completa y exhaustiva para validarlos?

Comment: No es lo mismo, yo solo busco una funci´´on no u evento de un edit text @Mariano

Comment: Sin embargo, es exactamente la misma lógica de esa respuesta. Está el regex y el if. No se necesita nada más que eso.

Comment: @AlbertoMier puedes usar el código de Mariano https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/74204/95 para solucionar este detalle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,4})$`

He encontrado esta expresión [aqui](http://librosweb.es/foro/pregunta/228/validando-direcciones-de-email-con-expresiones-regulares/) que también valida emails del tipo siguiente: `basta_con+un-ejemplo@un.sitio.museum`

El ejemplo del email ha sido aportado por: [Mariano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/127/mariano)

Comment: Esta expresión tiene un error gravísimo. No tiene los puntos escapados. Por eso es que acepta cualquier caracter. Pero también acepta cosas como `a/b@ja@ja@ja;ja`, lo cual está aberrantemente mal.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar esta regex en principio y luego ampliarla según te convenga:

```
    Pattern email_rj = Pattern.compile("^[a-z0-9]+([.][a-z0-9]+)*[@]+[a-z0-9]+[.]+[a-z]{3,4}$");
    boolean valid_em = email_rj.matcher("hola@dominio.com").matches();
```

Te permite ver exactamente qué es lo que estás validando.

#### Donde están la **ñ** y demás caracteres especiales?

Las direcciones que contienen caracteres no ASCII se incluyen en una norma llamada [IDN](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nombre_de_dominio_internacionalizado): cuando se entra una, para que sea compatible con el actual sistema de DNS se la debe convertir a [Punycode](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode%20Punycode) y luego ser buscada en su versión ASCII.

Por ejemplo si se entra `eñe.com`, en relidad la petición enviada es `xn--ee-zja.com`

Algo a tener en cuenta es que, en principio, esto no es un estándar totalmente implementado.

Incluso, cada proveedor de correo válida cómo quiere las direcciones que sus usuarios pueden crear.

Por ejemplo **Google** solo permite caracteres de la a-z, 0-9 y puntos.

La forma **más segura** de validar un email es enviado un correo a esta con un link de verificación, en vista de no caer en contradicciones.

Si solo quieres **avisar al usuario** de que introdujo el correo mal, sí puedes introducir los caracteres especiales en el regex, asumiendo ahora que su proveedor permite esto.

Comment: Esta expresión va a tomar como inválidas muchas direcciones válidas.

Comment: Puedes explicar tu respuesta? @Mariano

Comment: @Alberto `basta_con+un-ejemplo@un.sitio.museum`

Comment: @Alberto "correcta" es un término relativo (ver discusión en [Validar un email en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/142/127) donde se menciona que es prácticamente imposible validar todo el RFC, pero para los usos "comunes" de validación de e-mails "normales", yo usaría el regex que está en la respuesta aceptada... El mismo está adaptado a Java en [Solamente permitir escribir un correo electrónico en EditText](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/74174/127)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero no la puedo usar, me da error el android studio @Mariano

Comment: @AlbertoMier si querés, podemos verlo en el chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69209/consulta-regex-de-email-para-java debe ser algún detalle

Comment: @gabriel Incluso luego de tu modificación, tu expresión acepta direcciones como `8@@@@@@9.....abc` y no acepta `mi_nombre@hotmail.com.ar`

Comment: Como dije es para empezar, sin dudas no es algo en lo que te pasas solo 5 minutos, lo voy a hacer wiki a ver que tal

Answer (score 1):

El mismo [SDK de android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html) te ofrece varios patrones de expresiones regulares, existente a partir de API 8.

Para comprobar el email si es válido se usa `android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS`

Englobando en una función `isValidEmail("email")`

```
public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence email) {
    if (email== null) return false;
    return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
}
```

**Su uso**

`if (isValidEmail("tuemail@email.com") // true o false`

Comment: Está definido en http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/util/Patterns.java#Patterns.0EMAIL_ADDRESS, y realmente deja mucho que desear. Sigue un RFC viejo, que no acepta caracteres Unicode, ni muchos otros caracteres utilizados comúnmente.