# android Problema con validar el formato de email en un edittext

Tags: android, email, validación, edittext

Estoy intentando que en un editext que tienen que introducir un email, al ejecutar un onClick sobre un boton me compruebe que el formato de email es el correcto, ya he hecho un if para comprobar que los diferentes campos no están vacíos pero con el de el email no doy con la tecla.

```
public void onClick(View v) {


                if (validarVacios()) {

                    if (esEmailValido(compruebaemail)) {


                        // Gets the data repository in write mode
                        SQLiteDatabase db = Helper.getWritableDatabase();

                        // Create a new map of values, where column names are the keys
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(Estructura_BBDD.NOMBRE_COLUMNA1, txFecVisita.getText().toString());
                        values.put(Estructura_BBDD.NOMBRE_COLUMNA2, txTipoCliente.getText().toString());
                        values.put(Estructura_BBDD.NOMBRE_COLUMNA3, txNombre.getText().toString());
                        values.put(Estructura_BBDD.NOMBRE_COLUMNA4, txApellidos.getText().toString());
                        values.put(Estructura_BBDD.NOMBRE_COLUMNA5, txEmail.getText().toString());
                        values.put(Estructura_BBDD.NOMBRE_COLUMNA6, txTelefono.getText().toString());
                        values.put(Estructura_BBDD.NOMBRE_COLUMNA7, txFecNac.getText().toString());
                        values.put(Estructura_BBDD.NOMBRE_COLUMNA8, txCentroTrabajo.getText().toString());


                        // Insert the new row, returning the primary key value of the new row
                        long newRowId = db.insert(Estructura_BBDD.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "!!! Gracias " + txNombre.getText().toString() +
                                " por tu visita a Bosque Suspendido !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // DEJAR LIMPIOS LOS CAMPOS.

                        txFecNac.setText("");
                        txNombre.setText("");
                        txApellidos.setText("");
                        txEmail.setText("");
                        txTelefono.setText("");
                        txFecNac.setText("");
                        txCentroTrabajo.setText("");
                        txTipoCliente.setText("");
                    }

                }//fin If
            }

        });

 //Validación de que no hay campos vacios y formato email

    private boolean validarVacios(){
        boolean vacios = true;
                String c1 = txFecVisita.getText().toString();
                String c2 = txNombre.getText().toString();
                String c3 = txApellidos.getText().toString();
                String c4 = txEmail.getText().toString();
                String c5 = txTelefono.getText().toString();
                String c6 = txFecNac.getText().toString();


                if (c1.isEmpty()){
                    txFecVisita.setError("Este campo no puede quedar vacío");
                    vacios=false;
                }
                if (c2.isEmpty()){
                    txNombre.setError("Este campo no puede quedar vacío");
                    vacios=false;
                }
                if (c3.isEmpty()){
                    txApellidos.setError("Este campo no puede quedar vacío");

                    vacios=false;
                }
                if (c4.isEmpty()){
                    txEmail.setError("Este campo no puede quedar vacío");

                    vacios=false;
                }
                if (c5.isEmpty()){
                    txTelefono.setError("Este campo no puede quedar vacío");


                    vacios=false;
                }
                if (c6.isEmpty()){
                    txFecNac.setError("Este campo no puede quedar vacío");

                    vacios=false;
                }



        return vacios;


    }



    private boolean esEmailValido(String email) {
        boolean isValid ;//= true;



        String expression = "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";
        CharSequence inputStr = email;

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            isValid = true;
        }else{

            txEmail.setError("Este campo no ES UN PUTO MAIL");
            isValid = false;
        }

        return isValid;
    }



}
```

Comment: pero no estas checando si el email es valido o no? me parece que solo si esta vacio el TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para verificar el e-mail puedes [usar una REGEX](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/74204/95) o un [validador mediante un TextInputLayout](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/74183/95).

Para validar mediante una REGEX, puedes hacer uso de este método:

```
public boolean isValidEmail(String emailToReview){

    final String regex = "(?:[^<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+(?:\\.[^<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+)*|\"[^\\n\"]+\")@(?:[^<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+\\.)+[^<>()\\[\\]\\.,;:\\s@\"]{2,63}";

    if (!emailToReview.matches(regex)) {
        return false; //Es incorrecto
    }else{
        return true; // Es correcto
    }

}
```

llamarías de esta forma el método para determinar si el email es correcto:

```
        ...
        ...
        if (c4.isEmpty()){
            txEmail.setError("Este campo no puede quedar vacío");
            vacios=false;
        }else if (!isValidEmail(c4)){{ //Valida email.
            txEmail.setError("El email es incorrecto."); 
        }
        ...
        ...
```

---

Para validar mediante un  TextInputLayout  [aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/74183/95)

Comment: Te puse el error que me da la intentar lo que me indicaste. no se si es la forma mas correcta, si no, disculpa y muchísimas gracias

Comment: @AlfonsoAranda , perdón modifique el método, revisa la edición y ahora debe funcionar, saludos.

Comment: Genial, me ha servido, muchas gracias....