# Cómo validar correo en javascript

Tags: javascript, html

En `HTML` lo tengo así no sé de que forma validarlo ya que no quiero hacerlo por el `type="email"`

```html
<input class="input-100" type="email" name="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com " maxlength="39" id="email">
```

Comment: no entiendo esa forma

Comment: ¿No entiendes JavaScript?

Comment: osea si ya he usado javascript para validar pero bueno intente usar esa forma que sale en el enlace que pusistes pero no me sirvio y quisiera saber como puedo aplicarselo a mi input

Comment: Pues la respuesta a esta pregunta ya existe, es con JavaScript y y una expresión regular.

Comment: pero vaya yo se que tengo que mandar llamar el archivo js ... y la función donde debo mandarla a llamar?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Basado en lo que se ha respondido previamente [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/142/validar-un-email-en-javascript) (ya que comentas que no te queda claro como podrias hacerlo), te lo explicare de otra manera acerca de como podrias hacerlo:

```js
function validarEmail(elemento){

  var texto = document.getElementById(elemento.id).value;
  var regex = /^[-\w.%+]{1,64}@(?:[A-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.){1,125}[A-Z]{2,63}$/i;
  
  if (!regex.test(texto)) {
      document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "Correo invalido";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "";
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo Electronico" onkeyup="validarEmail(this)">
<a id='resultado'></a>
```

**Primero**

Creamos una funcion llamada `validarEmail()`, a la que le pasaremos como  parametro el elemento HTML, que corresponda al `<input>` donde se escribira el Correo Electronico. En esta funcion se validara el texto usando una expresion regular.

```
function validarEmail(elemento){

  var texto = document.getElementById(elemento.id).value;
  var regex = /^[-\w.%+]{1,64}@(?:[A-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.){1,125}[A-Z]{2,63}$/i;

  if (!regex.test(texto)) {
      document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "Correo invalido";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "";
  }

}
```

**Segundo**

Desde el elemento `<input>` agregaremos el evento `onkeyup()`, el cual se ejecutara ***cada que se presione una tecla***.

```
onkeyup="validarEmail(this)"
```

**Tercero**

Creamos un elemento de tipo `<a>` el cual tendra como identificador la palabra *resultado*, y desde la funcion `validarEmail()`, cambiaremos el texto de este dependiendo de la validacion del Correo Electronico.

```
<a id='resultado'></a>
```

**Ejemplo**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Titulo
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validarEmail(elemento) {

            var texto = document.getElementById(elemento.id).value;
            var regex = /^[-\w.%+]{1,64}@(?:[A-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.){1,125}[A-Z]{2,63}$/i;

            if (!regex.test(texto)) {
                document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "Correo invalido";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "";
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo Electronico" onkeyup="validarEmail(this)">
    <a id='resultado'></a>

</body>
</html>
```