# If con variable concatenada

Tags: javascript

Queria preguntar si puedo hacer que el usuario introduzca el inicio del correo ejemplo: `arturo.ortueta` y la validacion if pueda evaluar ejemplo `arturo.ortueta@gmail.com`

```js
var corr = prompt("Ingrese la primera parte del correo"); //ejemplo pondra arturo.ortueta
var correofull = corr + "@gmail.com";

if (correofull == corr + "@gmail.com") {

  document.write("Correcto");

} else {

  document.write("Incorrecto");

}
```

Queria saber si es posible realizar eso

Comment: Duda: ¿ya probaste este código?, por que así como esta es funcional

Comment: mas alla que siempre pero siempre va a dar true, el codigo anda.. cual seria el problema?

Comment: Después de crear `correofull` usa esa variable para validar con este ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/80178/c%c3%b3mo-validar-correo-en-javascript

Answer (score 0):

El código funciona, sin embargo no entiendo bien que estás validando, ¿Que hayan ingresado algo?.
Se me ocurre que podrías preguntar nombre y apellido por separado y concatenar todo.
Luego validar con una expresión regular el correo
Además te dejo un poquito mejorado ese código

```js
const fullname = prompt("Ingrese la primera parte del correo"); //ejemplo pondra arturo.ortueta
const email =  `${fullname}@gmail.com`;

if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email)) {

  console.log("Correcto");

} else {

  console.log("Incorrecto");

}
```

Saludos