# ¿Cómo puedo requerir el email?

Tags: php, html5

He metido un nuevo `<input type="email">` pero ¿cómo puedo poner aquí para que requiera el correo como los términos y condiciones y la contraseña?

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['registrar']) && isset($_REQUEST['reg_agree'])) {
if ($_REQUEST['contrasena'] === $_REQUEST['contrasenaConfirmar']) {
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$usuario = $_REQUEST['usuario'];
$password = $_REQUEST['contrasena'];

$encriptar = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ["cost" => '11']);
$conexion->query("INSERT INTO usuarios (email,usuario, contrasena) VALUES ('$email','$usuario', '$encriptar')");
$_SESSION['logged'] = "Logged";
$_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
$_SESSION['contrasena'] = $encriptar;
header("Location: login.php");
} else {
    echo "<div class='error'><span>Las Contraseñas no son iguales</span></div>";
    }
} elseif ( isset($_REQUEST['registrar']) && isset($_REQUEST['reg_agree']) === FALSE) {
    echo "<div class='error'><span>Necesitas Estar de Acuerdo con los Términos y Condiciones y Poner un Correo</span></div>";
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>

<link rel="StyleSheet" href="registro.css" media="all" type="text/css"></link>
<title>Registro</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="login">
    <form id="register-form" class="text-left" method="post">
    <h3>Registro</h3>
        <div class="main-login-form">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="reg_username" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="reg_password" name="contrasena" placeholder="Contraseña">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="reg_password_confirm" name="contrasenaConfirmar"placeholder="Confirmé contraseña">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox"  id="reg_agree" name="reg_agree">
                    <label for="reg_agree">de acuerdo con los <a href="terminosycondiciones.php">términos y condiciones</a></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button id="boton" type="submit" class="login-button" name="registrar"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right">Registrarme</i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="etc-login-form">
            <p>Ya tiene una cuenta? <a  style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none;"href="index.php">Login Aquí</a></p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Quieres hacerlo en javascript en la página que muestra el formulario y luego revalidar al recibir el formulario en el PHP o hacerlo únicamente en la recepción?

Comment: revalidar al recibir el formulario gracias de atemano.

Comment: Entonces debes prescindir del `header()` tal y como te mostraré en la respuesta.

Comment: ¿Has podido comprobar mi respuesta?

Comment: No entiendo esta pregunta. ¿Quieres requerir el email, o sea, que sea obligatorio introducirlo, o quieres validar el email? Un email se valida _realmente_ enviando y recibiendo una respuesta, no hay otro forma. Sugiero considerar **[esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/56203/29967)**  y todas las demás de esa pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

HTML:
Añade el atributo `required` a la etiqueta HTML:

PHP:
Si la variable email tiene un valor que siga el programa, o sino de error
if(isset[$_POST['email'])...

MYSQL
En la columna email de la tabla que no permita nulo. NOT NULL

Comment: gracias por todo es la leche este foro

Comment: @alberto este sitio no es un foro ;)

Comment: @lois6b y que es?

Comment: @alberto puedes leer la definicion de [Foro web](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foro_(Internet)). La cosa es que este **sitio** (perteneciente a la Red StackExchange) no sigue las mismas estructuras caracteristicas de un foro y tampoco tiene el mismo objetivo.

Comment: ¿He entendido mal la pregunta?

Comment: a vale :) :) :)

Comment: ok, acabo de aterrizar en este foro, digo, comunidad de ayuda, y no había visto comentarios debajo. Gracias por el -1 de bienvenida...xD

Comment: Te recomendaría cambiar la comprobación propuesta, `if(isset[$_POST['email'])`, será cierta siempre que hayan mandado el formulario, independientemente de su contenido.

Comment: Sí, se puede detallar con un conjunto de condicionales: que tenga al menos 6 caracteres, que tenga un arroba, que el arroba no esté ni al principio ni al final, etc. Gracias majo!

Answer (score 2):

Basta con agregar una nueva comprobación a tu PHP, aunque te recomiendo usar [`empty`](http://php.net/empty) para averiguar si está definido al mismo tiempo que no tenga un valor nulo (0, cadena vacía, etc):

> Determina si una variable es considerada vacía. Una variable se considera vacía si no existe o si su valor es igual a `FALSE`. `empty()` no genera una advertencia si la variable no existe.
>
> Las siguientes expresiones son consideradas como vacías:
>
> - "" (una cadena vacía)
> - 0 (0 como un integer)
> - 0.0 (0 como un float)
> - "0" (0 como un string)
> - NULL
> - FALSE
> - array() (un array vacío)
> - $var; (una variable declarada, pero sin un valor)

Te recomiendo, además, almacenar el mensaje en una variable para ponerla posteriormente bajo tu formulario y que así se muestre en vez de hacer un `echo` al principio de la página.

Lo más indicado sería capturar el envío del formulario mediante javascript y validar su contenido (aunque luego lo revalides en el PHP).

Te pongo el ejemplo de ambas cosas en el siguiente código:

```
<?php
/* El mensaje de error, por defecto, estará vacío */
$mensaje = '';
if (isset($_REQUEST['registrar']) && isset($_REQUEST['reg_agree']) && !empty($_REQUEST['email'])) {
    if ($_REQUEST['contrasena'] === $_REQUEST['contrasenaConfirmar']) {
        $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $usuario = $_REQUEST['usuario'];
        $password = $_REQUEST['contrasena'];

        $encriptar = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ["cost" => '11']);
        $conexion->query("INSERT INTO usuarios (email,usuario, contrasena) VALUES ('$email','$usuario', '$encriptar')");
        $_SESSION['logged'] = "Logged";
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        $_SESSION['contrasena'] = $encriptar;
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit();
    } else {
        $mensaje = "<div class='error'><span>Las Contraseñas no son iguales</span></div>";
    }
} else {
    $mensaje = "<div class='error'><span>Necesitas Estar de Acuerdo con los Términos y Condiciones y Poner un Correo</span></div>";
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="registro.css" media="all" type="text/css"></link>
    <title>Registro</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script>
    function comprobar_formulario(formulario) {
        if (formulario.reg_agree.checked == false) {
            alert("Acepte las condiciones");
            formulario.reg_agree.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (formulario.contrasena.value != formulario.contrasenaConfirmar.value) {
            alert("Las contraseñas no coinciden");
            formulario.contrasena.focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="login">
        <form name="formulario" id="register-form" class="text-left" method="post" onsubmit="return comprobar_formulario(this)">
            <h3>Registro</h3>
            <div class="main-login-form">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo" required>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="reg_username" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" required>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="email"  class="form-control" id="reg_email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="reg_password" name="contrasena" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="reg_password_confirm" name="contrasenaConfirmar"placeholder="Confirmé contraseña" required>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="checkbox"  id="reg_agree" name="reg_agree">
                        <label for="reg_agree">de acuerdo con los <a href="terminosycondiciones.php">términos y condiciones</a></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button id="boton" type="submit" class="login-button" name="registrar"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right">Registrarme</i></button>
            </div>
            <?= /* mostramos el mensaje de error almacenado */ $mensaje ?>
            <div class="etc-login-form">
                <p>Ya tiene una cuenta? <a  style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none;"href="index.php">Login Aquí</a></p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```