# ¿Cuál es el significado de los valores entre corchetes en una expresión regular?

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy validando una dirección de correo electrónico, y uso una expresión regular que vi [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/142/validar-un-email-en-javascript):

```
/^[-\w.%+]{1,64}@(?:[A-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.){1,125}[A-Z]{2,63}$/i
```

Mi problema es que quisiera saber cuál es la función de cada valor dentro de los corchetes en:

```
[-\w.%+]{1,64}
```

No termina de quedarme claro qué significa cada cosa en dicha expresión.

Comment: Exactamente ¿qué parte no entiendes? Porque parece que más que una duda estás pidiendo que se te explique todo lo de expresiones regulares, y para eso es mejor un tutorial (y si hay dudas con el tutorial, entonces poner la pregunta aquí)

Comment: No entiendo esta parte, lo demas anda bien. [-\w.%+]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad es bastante sencillo, pero lía porque algunos símbolos que aquí se usan como literales fuera del bracket son especiales.

`[-\w.%+]{1,64}` : Es el "nombre de usuario" de un e-mail

- `[]` Bracket, alternativa, reconoce cualquiera de los símbolos definidos dentro
- `-` El literal `-` (porque va al principio, si estuviera entre otros dos símbolos representaría el rango entre ambos: `0-9`).
- `\w` Clase `w`, que representa "símbolos que van en palabras"; letras y números: `A-Za-z0-9` y underscore `_`
- `.` El literal `.`, que es un símbolo válido en el e-mail. Fuera del bracket representa un comodín, pero dentro del bracket solo representa el literal.
- `%` El literal `%`, que es un símbolo válido en el e-mail.
- `+` El literal `+`, que es un símbolo válido en el e-mail. Fuera del bracket representaría "una o más repeticiones", pero dentro del bracket solo representa el literal.
- `{1,64}` De 1 a 64 repeticiones.

Ejemplo: https://regex101.com/r/eVaDQ3/1

Comment: Se llama "clase de caracteres" a la estructura de corchetes que coincide con un caracter.