# ¿Como hacer un pattern Regex en C# con el caracter '@'?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, regex

Buenas, quiero hacer un Pattern Regex para verificar que en una cadena exista el caracter arroba en medio de dos cadenas de texto en C#, lo convencional:

ejemplo@dominio.com.

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(email, "\@{1,1}")) {  
    //Codigo  
}
```

En el código anterior intentaba verificar que estuviera el caracter arroba al menos y máximo una vez en la cadena, pero supongo que \@ no es el regex corrector para referenciar ese caracter para un Regex.

Comment: tienes [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/142/validar-un-email-en-javascript) que es una regex para validar emails en JS. la regex es practicamente la misma. te sugiero que le eches un vistazo e intentes adaptarla a C#, Un saludo

Comment: si quieres comprobar direcciones de e-mail, hay numerosos regex disponibles. Por ejemplo, `^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como ya han contestado no es necesario escapar el signo @, por lo que una solución válida sería:

```
Regex.IsMatch(email, "[a-zA-Z]" + "@" + "[a-zA-Z"))
```

Si lo que quieres es validar una dirección de correo electrónico es mejor que uses el siguiente Regex:

```
@"^[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+(\.[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+)*" + "@"+ @"((([\-\w]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))$";
```

La clase MailAddress no detecta todos los casos (ej: abc.@def.com ó abc..123@def.com).

[Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342375/regex-email-validation) puedes encontrar más Regex (en inglés).

Comment: En ningún momento se dijo que tenía que haber una letra antes y después de la arroba... Y no entiendo para qué estás dividiendo el regex en 3 Strings que luego estás concatenado... Además, el regex que estás publicando para direcciones de mail falla con muchos casos comunes, por ejemplo con TLDs de más de 4 caracteres, y no recomendaría usarla para validar emails.

Comment: Cito textualmente la pregunta "(...) verificar que en una cadena exista el caracter arroba en medio de dos cadenas de texto (...". Lo he dividido así para que sea vea "mejor", y sí, es cierto que no detecta absolutamente todos, por esa razón he dejado el link donde hay más alternativas.

Comment: "*cadena de texto*" no es necesariamente una letra `[a-zA-Z]`... Y sigo sin entender para qué estás dividiendo el string en 3 diferentes, ni por qué usar un regex que tome como inválidas direcciones comunes

Answer (score 3):

En realidad te sobra la barra invertida. No necesitas escapar la @ en las expresiones regulares de .NET ya que no se trata de ningún carácter especial.

Puedes encontrar en internet muchos ejemplos de expresiones regulares para validar el formato de un email. Aunque también puedes utilizar el constructor de la clase `MailAddress` para comprobar si una cadena tiene un formato de email válido:

```
public bool IsValid(string emailaddress)
{
    try
    {
        MailAddress m = new MailAddress(emailaddress);

        return true;
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```