# Expresión regular de un email en C#

Tags: c#, regex

No manejo mucho esto de expresiones regulares espero me puedan ayudar, tengo una a la que debo modificar:

```
public static bool ValidarEmail(string email)
{
    return email != null && Regex.IsMatch(email, "^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@(([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.){1,2}[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$");
}
```

Siempre ha funcionado pero resulta que apareció un correo **xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@4life.com** que no pasa la validación debido a que tiene un número **(4)** como se puede observar sin embargo es un mail válido.

Comment: Dale una mirada a esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/142/validar-un-email-en-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres hacer esto...mucha suerte. Lo primero, no te olvides de que la comprobación **real** hay que hacerla en el servidor. Tienes funciones especializadas en PHP, C#, Perl y varios más para hacer esto, pero si quieres además hacerlo en el cliente, ahí va.

Tienes dos opciones: o escribir una expresión regular muy grande que valide absolutamente todos los casos admitidos en el estándar [RFC 5322](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt), o algo que sea más simple. Para la primera puedes usar la que recomienda el W3C en su [especificación de HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#valid-e-mail-address), que no es completa, pero captura el 99% de los correos:

`` /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/ ``

(Si usas la expresión regular de arriba, por favor, añade un comentario en tu código para que el pobre diablo que llegue detrás de ti sepa de dónde la sacaste y cómo buscar una nueva).

Para la segunda, si quieres algo más simple que puedas entender, aquí tienes otra:

`/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/`

Permite los siguientes formatos:

```
1.  normalito@example.com
2.  muy.comun@example.com
3.  disposable.style.email.with+symbol@example.com
4.  otro.correo-con-guiones@example.com
5.  #!$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}|~@example.org
6.  "()[]:,;@\\\"!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}| ~.a"@example.org
7.  " "@example.org (espacio entre las comillas)
8.  üñîçøðé@example.com (caracteres Unicode en la parte local)
9.  üñîçøðé@üñîçøðé.com (caracteres Unicode en la parte del dominio)
10. Pelé@example.com (Caracteres latinos)
11. δοκιμή@παράδειγμα.δοκιμή (Griego)
12. 我買@屋企.香港 (Chino)
13. 甲斐@黒川.日本 (Japonés)
14. чебурашка@ящик-с-апельсинами.рф (Cirílico)
```

Es muy versátil: admite todo tipo de caracteres internacionales, a la vez que obliga al correo a tener un aspecto como algo@algo.algo. En teoría se permiten los espacios en las direcciones de correo, pero esta expresión no los permite. En mi opinión, alguien que los use merece un castigo severo.

(Esta respuesta no es enteramente mía, sino que está extraída en parte y traducida de https://stackoverflow.com/a/32686261/374589).