# El navegador deja de formular peticiones ajax tras 8 peticiones

Tags: ajax

mi caso es:
Estoy realizando un login y quiero comprobar si el usuario existe ya en la base de datos, va bien, hasta que lo hace 8 veces (el usuario es un email, así que hay que escribir mas de 8 veces), después el método $.post deja de funcionar.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#email").on("keyup", function () {
                console.log("entro en el keyUp");
                $.post("<c:url value='/RegistroLogin'/>", {
                    datoEmail: $("#email").val()
                }, function (respuesta) {
                    if (respuesta == "true") {
                        console.log("usuario encontrado");
                        $("#enUso").html("<p class='bg-danger'>Usuario en uso</p>");
                    } else {
                        console.log("usuario no encontrado");
                        $("#enUso").html("<p class='bg-success'>Usuario disponible</p>");
                    }
                }).fail(function () {
                    console.log("FALLO");
                });
            });
        });
```

Estoy usando jsp, servlets y MySQL.
He de decir que CREO que lo que peta es el navegador, ya que si ejecuto la aplicación con otro navegador ajax responde perfectamente, hasta la 8a consulta(de nuevo).

Es mi primera pregunta, si faltan detalles avisarme, muchas gracias.

EDITO: añado la pestaña network en chrome y firefox
[image: Network Firefox Developer Edition]
[image: Network Chrome]

Comment: Significa que cuando escribes 8 caracteres el noveno no gatilla una llamada ajax? Has inspeccionado la pestaña `network` ya sea en Chrome o  en Firefox? Además te recomendaría no hacer esa comprobación con cada tecla. No sería mejor esperar a que ocurra el vento `blur`, cuando el usuario haya terminado de escribir su correo y se cambie de input, o intente enviar el formulario?

Comment: Tu problema puede estar en la saturación del servidor, que escribes mas rápido de lo que te responde. Ahora como sugerencia, creo que sería mejor que compruebes que tiene un formato de mail, con una `expresión regular` y luego en el evento `OnBlur`, compruebes el uso del mail en la base de datos.

Comment: Acabo de añadir pantallazos de network @amenadiel , y tenéis razón es mejor usar blur, aunque pierda el foco rápidamente ya no peta y resuelve las peticiones, muchísimas gracias a los dos, de verdad. Soy nuevo por aquí, en los comentarios no se puede dar voto positivo ni daros puntos?

Comment: ok entonces el problema no era que no se gatillaran las peticiones, sino que no se resolvían. @JoseJavierSegura ¿Quieres redactar una respuesta para que el usuario marque la pregunta como solucionada?

Comment: ¿Es probable que sea un método de seguridad contra sobrecarga del servidor al usar "keyup"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viendo las pantallas, queda claro que tu problema esta en la demora del servidor a tus peticiones `AJAX`.

Para evitar esto, lo mejor que puedes hacer es en el evento `Onkeyup`, usar alguna expresión regular para comprobar si es una mail. Una posible solución sería

```
$("#email").on("keyup", function () {
console.log("entro en el keyUp");
var MailRegEx=/^[-\w.%+]{1,64}@(?:[A-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.){1,125}[A-Z]{2,63}$/i;
if (MailRegEx.test($("#email").val())){
    console.log("usuario válido"); //Es una dirección de email
    $("#enUso").html("<p class='bg-danger'>Usuario Válido</p>");
}
else{
    console.log("usuario no válid"); //No es una dirección de mail
    $("#enUso").html("<p class='bg-success'>Usuario No válido</p>");
}                
)};
```

Luego una vez sea valida la dirección de mail, en el evento OnBlur, podrías hacer tu llamada `AJAX`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#email").on("blur", function () {
                console.log("entro en el keyUp");
                $.post("<c:url value='/RegistroLogin'/>", {
                    datoEmail: $("#email").val()
                }, function (respuesta) {
                    if (respuesta == "true") {
                        console.log("usuario encontrado");
                        $("#enUso").html("<p class='bg-danger'>Usuario en uso</p>");
                    } else {
                        console.log("usuario no encontrado");
                        $("#enUso").html("<p class='bg-success'>Usuario disponible</p>");
                    }
                }).fail(function () {
                    console.log("FALLO");
                });
            });
        });
```

**PD** Esta actualizada la Expresión regular del mail

Comment: Buena solución, sólo que ese regex toma como inválidas muchas direcciones válidas. Recomendaría usar el de [Validar un email en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/142/127).