# Validar 2 expresiones regulares en una

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo la siguiente expresión regular

```
/^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i
```

Para validar correos, además debo validar que el correo no contenga la palabra "notiene" y la expresión es `/^((?!notiene).)*$`, sin embargo no logro mezclar las dos.

Comment: En vez de esta expresión para mails, conviene que uses la segunda que está en la respuesta a [Validar un email en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/151/127)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**El problema**. La [inspección negativa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-negated-look-ahead) (*negative lookahead*) que estás usando, parte desde el inicio del texto, y va consumiendo cada uno de los caracteres siempre que no estén seguidos por `notiene`

```
/^((?!notiene).)*$/
```

Eso hace que cuando intente validar el mail, ya se va a encontrar en el final del texto. Es decir, el `.*` de ese patrón ya consumió todos los caracteres, sin permitir que haya más para validar.

**La solución**. En cambio, si se valida desde el inicio del texto, pero no se consume ningún caracter, entonces se puede validar más de un subpatrón:

```
/^(?!.*notiene)expresión2$/i
```

Una inspección intenta coincidir con el subpatrón y, luego de coincidir, el cursor sigue desde la misma posición en la que estaba antes de intentar dicha inspección. Se puede pensar como una construcción que únicamente devuelve verdadero/falso, pero el resto del regex puede seguir como si nada hubiese pasado (*si devolvió verdadero, claro*).

Con `^(?!.*notiene)` nos aseguramos de que se recorra toda la línea. Si `.*notiene` no coincide, al ser una inspección **negativa** entonces es como que devolviera "*verdadero*", pero aún estamos en el inicio del texto (no se consumió ningún caracter), y podemos verificar cualquier otro patrón a partir de ahí.

**Regex completo:** (usando la respuesta de [Validar un email en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/151/127))

```
/^(?!.*notiene)(?:[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+)*|"[^\n"]+")@(?:[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@"]{2,63}$/i
```

**Demo:**

```js
document.getElementById('email').addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
    campo = evt.target;
    valido = document.getElementById('emailOK');
        
    emailRegex = /^(?!.*notiene)(?:[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+)*|"[^\n"]+")@(?:[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@"]{2,63}$/i;
    //Se muestra un texto a modo de ejemplo
    if (emailRegex.test(campo.value)) {
      valido.innerText = "válido";
    } else {
      valido.innerText = "incorrecto";
    }
});
```

```html
Email que no tenga "notiene":
<input id="email">
<span id="emailOK"></span>
```

**Caso general**

Para cualquier caso donde tengamos 2 expresiones regulares ancladas al inicio del texto (sí, tienen que coincidir *desde* el inicio), sean `^re1` y `^re2`, la forma de verificar a ambas es:

```
/^(?=re1)re2/
```

O, como en tu caso, que **no** coincida la primera, pero sí la segunda:

```
/^(?!re1)re2/
```

Por ejemplo, uniendo 3 expresiones: *que tenga una mayúscula, que no termine en "1234" y que tenga entre 8 y 200 caracteres*.

```
/^(?=.*[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ])(?!.*1234$).{8,200}$/
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu completa explicación, desconozco mucho el tema de regex, aveces es llegar y copiar de google o alguna respuesta de stack over flow

Comment: Nunca es tarde para estudiarlo ;-) Si en algún momento te interesás, sabés dónde encontrarme.