# Explicación de expresión regular /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/

Tags: javascript, regex

¿Alguien me puede explicar esta línea, carácter a carácter?

(Valida un email, correctamente)

```
/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/
```

Comment: La línea que nos pasas parece más bien una expresión regular y no es una particularidad de javascript, deberías editar las etiquetas de la pregunta para que coincidan con lo que preguntas.

Comment: Todas las preguntas de [tag:regex] dependen del lenguaje. Por favor, tener en cuenta los puntos solicitados en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lo que estás mostrando es un regex (una expresión regular). Antes que nada, esa expresión es muy limitada y **va a fallar con muchos ejemplos de mails cotidianos**, por ejemplo: `abc#mnño@ej.museum`. Además, tiene varios errores graves (que escapan al alcance de tu pregunta). Dejame decirlo claro: es *horrible*.

> Deberías usar el regex de [Validar un email en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/142/127).

Si bien **jamás te recomendaría usar el regex de tu pregunta**, tomemos al siguiente, que es una versión en la que arreglé varios errores que tenías (pero aún así seguirá fallando con algunos casos):

```
/^\w+([.-]\w+)*@\w+([.-]\w+)*\.\w{2,4}$/
```

En JavaScript, esa notación genera un objeto [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp).

```
var miRegex = /^\w+([.-]\w+)*@\w+([.-]\w+)*\.\w{2,4}$/;
```

Esto es una forma simplificada de (y exactamente lo mismo que) llamar al constructor:

```
var miRegex = new RegExp('^\\w+([.-]\\w+)*@\\w+([.-]\\w+)*\\.\\w{2,4}$');
```

#### Descripción

```
/^\w+([.-]\w+)*@\w+([.-]\w+)*\.\w{2,4}$/

^ ::: Coincide con el inicio del texto

\w+ ::: \w es lo mismo que [a-zA-Z_0-9] (un caracter alfanumérico)
        El + lo repite 1 o más veces.
        Es decir, coincide con 1 o más caracteres alfanuméricos.

([.-]\w+)* ::: Es un grupo, repetido * (0 o más veces)
    Coincide con:
    [.-] ::: un punto o un guión
    \w+  ::: 1 o más caracteres alfanuméricos.
    Esto sirve para permitir puntos o guiones 
    que no estén ni al principio ni al final del usuario.

@ ::: una arroba literal

\w+ ::: 1 o más caracteres alfanuméricos
([.-]\w+)* ::: un punto o guión intermedio con más alfanuméricos
               de nuevo, repetido 0 o más veces

\.\w{2,4} ::: un punto seguido de 2 a 4 alfanuméricos.
          Esto es para el TLD (la extensión), aunque es un error limitarla a 2-4!!!

$ ::: Coincide con el final del texto
```

Si quisieras validar un texto en tu código:

```
if (miRegex.test(algunTexto)) {
    // ...
}
```

Más información en [Expresiones Regulares (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score -3):

Creo que seria algo así:

```
/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/
```

Cadena de caracteres que puede incluir punto(.) y guion(-)(solo uno seguido), luego un arroba(@), luego una cadena de caracteres que puede incluir punto(.) y guion(-)(solo uno seguido), luego un punto(.) y luego una cadena de caracteres alfabéticos de de longitud 2 a 4.

Espero que alguien me pueda editar la parte de `([\.-]?\w+`, pero creo que es que no se pueden poner mas de un carácter de esos seguidos.

Answer (score -3):

Las expresiones regulares son patrones utilizados para encontrar una determinada combinación de caracteres dentro de una cadena de texto.

**EJEMPLO**

- ?
         El signo de interrogación indica que el carácter que le precede puede aparecer como mucho una vez. Por ejemplo, "ob?scuro" se
  corresponde con oscuro y obscuro.
- +
         El signo más indica que el carácter que le precede debe aparecer al menos una vez. Por ejemplo, "ho+la" describe el conjunto
  infinito hola, hoola, hooola, hoooola, etcétera.

  *
- El asterisco indica que el carácter que le precede puede aparecer
  cero, una, o más veces. Por ejemplo, "0*42" se corresponde con 42,
  042, 0042, 00042, etcétera.

Dado que la explicacion seria amplia por todos los simbolos y caracteres que emplea este te facilito un link donde esta detallado las  expresiones regulares.
[regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)