# Consulta con OR para solucion de inicio de sesión mediante EMAIL o NOMBRE DE USUARIO

Tags: php, sql

¿Es correcta esta consulta? En principio no da error, pero creo que no está respondiendo como yo quiero:

Por motivo de que a veces los usuarios en vez de introducir en el inicio de sesión EMAIL y CONTRASEÑA, introducen NOMBRE DE USUARIO y CONTRASEÑA, quería que la consulta mire las dos opciones. Pero tengo dudas con ese OR. Si se pone paréntesis, etc.

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios 
WHERE (emailUsuario = '$emailUsuario' OR nombreusuarioUsuario = '$emailUsuario')
AND passwordUsuario = '$passwordUsuario'
```

¿O debería ser?

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios
WHERE (emailUsuario = '$emailUsuario' AND passwordUsuario = '$passwordUsuario')
OR (nombreusuarioUsuario = '$nombreusuarioUsuario' AND passwordUsuario = '$passwordUsuario')
```

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: la primera es correcta, por que validará si no es el email entonces será el nombre de usuario

Comment: Diría que ninguna de las dos son correctas, aunque puede que funcione. El que algo funcione no significa que sea correcto. Y preguntaría, ¿qué te impide ser **preciso y coherente** en tu código? Si vas a evaluar el nombre es el nombre, no el email y viceversa. En mi opinión, lo que tendrías que hacer es **controlar qué campos llenó el usuario** y en base a eso construir la consulta.

Comment: Gracias. Lo que ocurre es que son sólo dos campos (input) con sus placeholder indicando "email" y "contraseña". Lo que ocurre es que hay usuarios que en vez de introducir el email introducen su nombre de usuario. Les da error y tras varios intentos se van de la web. (A pesar de poner un mensaje por GET indicando "Debe ntroducir el EMAIL y la CONTRASEÑA). Por eso, he decidio permittir el nombre de usuario en el campo contraseña. ¿Mala idea? Gracias.

Comment: Sí, es mala idea. Pongo un ejemplo: si estás enseñando a alguien a comer, y esa persona intenta usar el tenedor para comerse la sopa ... no eres un buen maestro si eres indiferente y le dejas que se coma la sopa con el tenedor. Te toca ejercer la función de enseñante y decirle que la sopa se come con la cuchara. Es lo mismo en tu código, tienes que programar la interfaz de forma que los usuarios sepan lo que tienen que hacer. Si lo propio es que escriban sólo el email, no permitas que escriban el nombre como si fuera el email. Si es posible uno u otro, entonces pon un ....

Comment: ... input para el email y otro para el nombre. Cuando haya datos en uno, desactiva el otro y viceversa. Así, según el input que haya sido llenado sabrás si el usuario intentó autenticarse con el email o con el nombre. O usa otro método, como por ejemplo buscar si en el texto existe el caracter `@` o algo así. Lo que no estoy de acuerdo es con un código loco que trate el email como si fuera el nombre o viceversa. El email es el email y el nombre es el nombre.

Comment: Entendido, tienes razón. He puesto un control javascript para que cuando introducen algo que no tiene formato de email ponga el borde en color rojo. ¿Mejor? Saludos.

Comment: Yo opino que está bien que permitas que el usuario decida si quiere poner su correo o username, no existe tal cosa como correcto o incorrecto en este caso. Es a tu gusto, a mi me molesta que me pidan a fuerzas el correo o el username. Me encanta que me dejen decidir. Quien decide que es correcto o no, eres tú mismo.

Comment: Si el método de validación es el email, es correcto. Además es muy fácil saber cuando alguien está introduciendo un email, como lo que comentas de detectar si existe el carácter `@` en el contenido (para la validación de un email en Javascript puedes consultar [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/142/29967) y sus respuestas). @memoadian no me opongo a que se permita el uso del nombre, pero identificando posteriormente de alguna manera el método que el usuario haya elegido (nombre o email) para lanzar la consulta específica, no mezclando cosas en la consulta.

Comment: GMAIL por ejemplo permite las dos opciones para inciar sesión. ¿Lo hará Google mal por dejar tomar la sopa con tenedor? xD (bromeo) Gracias a todos.

Comment: No creo que Google te deje tomar la sopa con el tenedor, seguro que Google examina de alguna manera lo que has escrito y en base a eso consulta por el nombre o por el email. Lo que yo no veo bien es hacer comparaciones de este tipo `emailUsuario = '$emailUsuario' OR nombreusuarioUsuario = '$emailUsuario'` en las que se usa una misma variable para dos comparaciones en dos campos distintos.