# Validacion de correo con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Los interrumpo porque necesito ayuda con la validacion de un correo electronico para un formulario de contacto, es sencillo lo se, pero no me esta saliendo satisfactoriamente. Aca les dejo lo que tengo hecho.

Gracias!

```js
var email = document.getElementById("email");
            email.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
                if (email.validity.typeMismatch) {
                    email.setCustomValidity("¡Debes ingresar una cuenta de correo electrónico!");
                } else {
                    email.setCustomValidity("");
                }
            });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form class="form">
                <h4>Solicitud de información</h4>
                <div class="form active">
                <textarea name="mensaje" rows="" cols="" style="height:100px">Hola, quiero que me contacten. ¡Gracias!</textarea>
                </div>   
                <div class="form">
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="ejemplo@mail.com" required onkeyup="validarEmail(this)"/>
                <a id='resultado'></a>
                </div>
                <div class="form">
                <input type="text" required placeholder="Nombre"/>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="contactar">
                <input type="submit" id="entrar" onclick="location.href='index.html'" value="volver a la pagina">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: En este caso si ya estas creando un listener del lado del java script no es necesario que le indiques del lado del html la función a ejecutar, o en el caso declarar la función ya que actualmente en tu código no existe la función validarEmail

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Validar un email en JavaScript que acepte todos los caracteres latinos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/142/validar-un-email-en-javascript-que-acepte-todos-los-caracteres-latinos). En varias respuestas se indica la [expresión regular requerida](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#valid-e-mail-address) para validar un email y se ponen ejemplos de cómo usarla. Se dan también otras posibilidades de validación.

Answer (score 1):

**Buen día, quizá este código te ayude!**

```js
function isValidEmail(email){
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}
    
    $('.jsButtonValidate').on('click', ()=>{    
      let valueEmail = $('.jsEmail').val();
      
      if(isValidEmail(valueEmail)){
        alert('Correo Válido');
      }
      else{
        alert('Correo INCORRECTO!');
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="jsEmail">
<button class="jsButtonValidate">Validar</button>
```