# Como mostrar alert al momento de enviar

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Estoy realizando una función con Javascript para validar que un correo electrónico es valido, al momento de la validación y que el correo no sea valido quiero que me muestre un alert, para crear el alert estoy ayudándome con la versión 3.3.7 de Bootstrap.

El siguiente es un snippet en el que estoy creando mi formulario

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 row2">

                                        <input type="email" name="Contacto" id="Contacto" value="" size="50" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 row2">
                                        <button class="EnviarContactoDetalleProducto btn-lg" id="Contacto" onclick="EnviarInformacion"> Enviar</button>
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger">La dirección de email es incorrecta!.</div>
                                    </div>
```

La siguiente es la función que estoy usando en mi Javascript para validar el correo y que se muestre el mensaje.

```
function EnviarInformacion() {

    var Contacto = $("#Contacto").val();

    if (/^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i.test(Contacto)) {
        alert("La dirección de email " + Contacto + " es correcta!.");
    } else {
        alert("La dirección de email es incorrecta!.");
        
    }

}
```

No quiero que se muestre el alert tradicional de los navegadores, quiero que se muestre el alert de Bootstrap pero solo al momento de que un correo no sea valido.

**Actualización:**

Cuando escribo una dirección de correo no valida me muestra el mensaje como la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando escribo una dirección valida se sigue mostrando el mensaje de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No quisiera que se muestre el mensaje al introducir una dirección de correo valida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que necesitas es identificar la alerta, para eso le pondremos un id:

```
<div id="alert" class="alert alert-danger">La dirección de email es incorrecta!.</div>
```

luego lo que tienes que hacer es ocultar la alerta, esto lo podrías lograr con css y de paso ponerle una transición para que se vea un poco mejor, por ejemplo:

```
.alert{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

luego necesitas otra clase para mostrar la alerta, esto de nuevo se puede hacer con css:

```
.show{
 opacity: 1;
}
```

y por ultimo necesitamos que cuando enviamos el formulario dependiendo de si el correo es valido o no se muestre la alerta:

```
function EnviarInformacion() {

    var Contacto = $("#Contacto").val();
    const alerta = document.getElementById("alert")

    if (/^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i.test(Contacto)) {
        return
    } else {
        alerta.classList.add("show")            
    }

}
```

Comment: La validación esta funcionando al revés, lo hice como tu código pero entonces me esta mostrando el mensaje de correo invalido y se esta enviando sin importar la caracteres

Comment: Probablemente esta mal la expresión regular

Comment: Con los alerts tradicionales del navegador si me funciona como debe ser la validación, tome la respuesta de [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/142/validar-un-email-en-javascript-que-acepte-todos-los-caracteres-latinos)

Comment: Que raro que con los alerts te funcione normal, intenta hacer console log de ```/^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i.test(Contacto)``` antes del if y fíjate si te sale true o false

Comment: Lo revise y es problema de la validación, ahora estoy presentando otro problema, cuando introduzco una dirección de correo no valida me sale el mensaje correctamente, pero cuando sigo escribiendo en el campo el mensaje se sigue mostrando, como hago para cuando escriba la dirección de correo valida ya no se muestre, revisa mi pregunta hice una actualización.